# Decay Constant for Normalized Exponential Time Decay with Constraint on Output at given time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> I have an exponential decay function
>   $$
> N(t) = N_0 e ^ {-\lambda t}
> $$
>   where $t\in[1,T]$, $N_0$ is the normalization constant for that time window $1$ to $T$
>   ... ex $\sum_{t=1}^{T} e ^ {\lambda t}$ for some time window $T$
>
> where $\lambda$ must be found to satisfy the constraint $N(12) = 0.05$

I thought this would be quite easy, but I've been having difficulty due to the normalizing constant. I got the equation to the form: $$\lambda = \ln(0.05) / \prod_{t=1}^T t-12 $$
but that results in $-\infty$ due to the product part evaluating to 0... I'm hoping I just messed up somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If neither $N_0$ or $\lambda$ are given you cannot find them both from a single constraint. Presuming that $N_0$ or a second constraint allowing you to calculate $N_0$ is given, you can find $\lambda$ by
$$
-12\lambda  = \ln (N(12)/ N_0).
$$
If $N(t)$ is supposed to be normalized on $[1,T]$ the sense that 
$$
\int_1^T N(t)\ dt = 1,
$$
this second constraint becomes
$$
1 = \int_1^T N(t)\ dt = \int_1^T N_0e^{-\lambda t}\ dt = -\frac{N_0}{\lambda}(e^{-\lambda T} - e^{-\lambda}).
$$
Thus, presuming $T$ is given, you can solve the nonlinear system
$$
e^{-12\lambda} = \frac{N(12)}{N_0}, \ \ \frac{1}{N_0} = -\frac{1}{\lambda}(e^{-\lambda T} - e^{-\lambda}).
$$

You can eliminate $N_0$ to give you

$$
e^{-12\lambda} =-\frac{N(12)}{\lambda}(e^{-\lambda T} - e^{-\lambda}),
$$
which can be solved using a nonlinear root finder.

Comment: all of the results from wolfram have an imaginary component, does this mean it is unsolvable?

Comment: I'm also a bit curious why replacing $N_0$ with a function only dependent on $\lambda$ for a given T wouldn't work with just constraint? Since $\lambda$ would be the only unknown

Comment: @Alter well I did make an algebra mistake (now fixed) so that could have been the reason for the imaginary component; try again.

Comment: No real for T=30 and N(12) = 0.05 still :(